# XSLT custom function returning nodeset or XML fragment (not simple datatype)

Tags: java, xslt

I am trying to develop an XSLT custom function that could return node set or an XML fragment, let's say something like:

Input document:

```
<root>
<!--
 author: blablabla
 usage: more blablabla
 labelC: [in=2] <b>formatted</b> blablabla
-->
<tag1 name="first">
    <tag2>content a</tag2>
    <tag2>content b</tag2>
    <tag3 attrib="val">content c</tag3>
</tag1>

<!--
 author: blebleble
 usage: more blebleble
 labelC: blebleble
-->
<tag1 name="second">
    <tag2>content x</tag2>
    <tag2>content y</tag2>
    <tag3 attrib="val">content z</tag3>
</tag1>
</root>
```

So that an XSLT template such as:

```
    <xsl:template match="//tag1/preceding::comment()[1]" xmlns:d="java:com.dummy.func">
    <section>
     <para>
      <xsl:value-of select="d:genDoc(.)"/>
     </para>
    </section>
    </xsl:template>
```

Would produce:

```
    <section>
     <para>
      <author>blablabla</author>
      <usage>more blablabla</usage>
      <labelC in="2"><b>formatted</b> blablabla</labelC>
     </para>
    </section>
```

When matched on the first occurrence of tag1
and

```
    <section>
     <para>
      <author>blebleble</author>
      <usage>more blebleble</usage>
      <labelC>blebleble</labelC>
     </para>
    </section>
```

When matched on the second occurrence.

**Basically what I want to achieve with this custom function is to parse some meta-data present in the comments and use it to generate XML.**

I found some examples online, one at:
http://cafeconleche.org/books/xmljava/chapters/ch17s03.html

According to the example, my function should return one of the following

```
org.w3c.dom.traversal.NodeIterator,
org.apache.xml.dtm.DTM,
org.apache.xml.dtm.DTMAxisIterator,
org.apache.xml.dtm.DTMIterator,
org.w3c.dom.Node and its subtypes (Element, Attr, etc),
org.w3c.dom.DocumentFragment
```

I was able to implement a function returning the XML as simple type String.
This, however poses several other problems: the main being the markers characters get escaped when inserted in the original XML.

Does anybody have an example of how to implement such function?
I am mostly interested in how to return a proper XML node set to the calling template.

Comment: Could you explain, what your function should do? What are the "relevant" parts of the xml and how does your first code example differ to the third one? Are you sure, you really need to write a custom function?

Comment: The aim of the function is to parse information stored in a comment in an xml file and to generate an intermediate xml structure for further processing eg. docbook generation). The code I reported here is oversimplified as I wanted to focus only on the java custom function, but you could imagine to process all the comments in a pre-determined position in the source document, parse them with the custom function and generate the intermediate structure (somewhat similar to <int><tag1>[...] code. Hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: I don't see no comments in your examples... could you edit your post so that it shows what you actually want to do?

Comment: Hi Chris, I added some more comment and changed a bit the code, hope this makes it more clear. Thank for your interest in my question.

Comment: Okay now in understand what you're trying to do, but can you explain what you need this for? Could you maybe make your examples more "real"  so that you don't have "tag1" and "blebleble" but some things with meaning instead so that one could see what you're trying to do here?

Comment: @Chris Hi Chris, the aim is to generate documentation (in DocBook) from the comments stored in the xml files. `tag1` are tasks definitions (a bit like ant's tasks) and the comment preceding them lists author, parameters, description, usage examples, etc...

Comment: @Daniele this may have escaped your attention, because no proper answer has been supplied for over two months now - but I think you will really like my answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

The below may get you a long way along the road you want to go. Note that this requires XSLT 2.0 version (in XSLT 1.0 it will be possible too, when supplying a replacement function for `tokenize`). Also note that this assumes a specific comment contents structure.
Explanation: comments are first split up into rows (delimiter `& #xD;` which is a line-feed), then in tag+value (delimiter ":", splitting into author, usage, labelC, the order is not important here), then in attributes and value for labelC (delimiter "] ", recognizing attributes as starting with "[").
Note that a lot of whitespace-wiping is done using `normalize-space()`.

Edited: xslt version with function see at the bottom

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <output>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </output>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tag1/*">
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="comment()">
        <section>
            <para>
                <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '&#xD;')[string-length() != 0]">
                    <xsl:variable name="splitup" select="tokenize(normalize-space(current()), ':')"/>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$splitup[1]='author'">
                            <author><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($splitup[2])"/></author>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$splitup[1]='usage'">
                            <usage><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($splitup[2])"/></usage>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$splitup[1]='labelC'">
                            <labelC>
                                <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($splitup[2], '] ')[string-length() != 0]">
                                    <xsl:variable name="labelCpart" select="normalize-space(current())"/>
                                    <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when test="substring($labelCpart, 1,1) = '['">
                                            <xsl:variable name="attr" select="tokenize(substring($labelCpart, 2), '=')"/>
                                            <xsl:attribute name="{$attr[1]}"><xsl:value-of select="$attr[2]"/></xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="$labelCpart"/>
                                        </xsl:otherwise>
                                    </xsl:choose>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </labelC>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </para>
        </section>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<!--
 author: blablabla
 usage: more blablabla
 labelC: [in=2] <b>formatted</b> blablabla
-->
<tag1 name="first">
    <tag2>content a</tag2>
    <tag2>content b</tag2>
    <tag3 attrib="val">content c</tag3>
</tag1>

<!--
 author: blebleble
 usage: more blebleble
 labelC: blebleble
-->
<tag1 name="second">
    <tag2>content x</tag2>
    <tag2>content y</tag2>
    <tag3 attrib="val">content z</tag3>
</tag1>
</root>
```

gives the following output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
    <section>
        <para>
            <author>blablabla</author>
            <usage>more blablabla</usage>
            <labelC in="2">&lt;b&gt;formatted&lt;/b&gt; blablabla</labelC>
        </para>
    </section>
    <section>
        <para>
            <author>blebleble</author>
            <usage>more blebleble</usage>
            <labelC>blebleble</labelC>
        </para>
    </section>
</output>
```

**EDITED** xslt with function call (gives the same output)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:d="java:com.dummy.func"
exclude-result-prefixes="d">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <output>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </output>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tag1/*">
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="d:section">
        <xsl:param name="comm"/>
        <section>
            <para>
                <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($comm, '&#xD;')[string-length() != 0]">
                    <xsl:variable name="splitup" select="tokenize(normalize-space(current()), ':')"/>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$splitup[1]='author'">
                            <author><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($splitup[2])"/></author>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$splitup[1]='usage'">
                            <usage><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($splitup[2])"/></usage>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$splitup[1]='labelC'">
                            <labelC>
                                <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($splitup[2], '] ')[string-length() != 0]">
                                    <xsl:variable name="labelCpart" select="normalize-space(current())"/>
                                    <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when test="substring($labelCpart, 1,1) = '['">
                                            <xsl:variable name="attr" select="tokenize(substring($labelCpart, 2), '=')"/>
                                            <xsl:attribute name="{$attr[1]}"><xsl:value-of select="$attr[2]"/></xsl:attribute>
                                        </xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="$labelCpart"/>
                                        </xsl:otherwise>
                                    </xsl:choose>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </labelC>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </para>
        </section>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="comment()">
        <xsl:copy-of select="d:section(.)"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```